# Using Poedit on blade files

Tags: php, translation, laravel-blade, poedit

I am using Poedit to create my translation files. But in our project, any translation like this, aren't recognized by Poedit.

```
<span>{{translate('Services')}}</span>
```

I am using translate as a keyword.

It works within php tags, like this, but I would prefer not to do it this way.

```
<span><?php echo translate('Services'); ?></span>
```

From what I searched, Poedit 2.0, which I am using is supposed to understand such tags inside blade files, but clearly it's not working.

Is there some configuration change I can do to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: i think your are getting things mixed up. .po files know nothing about laravel or blade. does laravel support .po files?

Comment: actually, yes, i remember in poedit telling it what the translate function for zend framework. i misunderstood your question, yes poedit can scan your files looking for whatebver you tell it to

Comment: use `php artisan view:cache` then scan cache directory of views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything built into Laravel that will handle .po files but there may be a package available somewhere out there.

Traditionally in Laravel translated text is handled by defining a language file in `resources/lang/en` ( or another language directory beneath `resources/lang`).

To fetch text from a language file one can use the `trans()` helper function in a blade.

More information about localization and language files:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#introduction

**A basic example:**

resources/lang/en/tests.php

```
return [
'one' => 'This is test one!',
'two' => 'This is test two!'
];
```

resources/views/tests.blade.php

```
<p>Hello world! {{trans('tests.one')}}</p>
```

Produces:

```
Hello World! This is test one!
```